# Context menu on Chrome turns blank when mouse is over

Tags: 14.04, gnome, google-chrome

I am using Ubuntu GNOME and when I am on Google Chrome the **context menu turns blank when the cursor is over an option**. Only Google Chrome has this issue. Here a screenshot:

[image: Chrome context menu blank]

I have tested on Unity, KDE and Gnome Classic and it works fine. I've seen this bug only on GNOME 3.10 and 3.12. Is this bug related to GNOME or Google Chrome? Do you know how to solve this or do I need to wait a new version of Google Chrome (or GNOME)?

The versions:

- Ubuntu GNOME 14.04.1 LTS
- GNOME 3.12;
- Google Chrome 36.0.1985.125;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and for me the solution was choosing "Use GTK+ Theme" in Settings -> Appearence.